# How to set a breakpoint in arrow function

Tags: node.js, webstorm

```
  return db.user.findOne({nickname: {$regex: new RegExp("^" + name, "i")}})
                .exec()
                .then(user => !!user);
```

When i was debugging above code, i wish to watch the user value. But because it's in arrow function, `webstorm` won't stop at `user=> !!user`. The only thing i can do to make breakpoint works is to change code like this:

```
  return db.user.findOne({nickname: {$regex: new RegExp("^" + name, "i")}})
                .exec()
                .then(user => function() {return !!user});
```

But it doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just break line and set breakpoint at new line:

```
  return db.user.findOne({nickname: {$regex: new RegExp("^" + name, "i")}})
                .exec()
                .then(
  /**breakpoint**/ user => !!user
                );
```