# Debug arrow function when parameter have specific value

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want so start debug when parameter of function have some specific value suppose with this function

```
const findGCD = nums => {
    const gcd = (a, b) =>  b === 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    return nums.reduce(gcd);
}

console.log(findGCD([20,8,32,30,36,16,51]))
```

I want to start debug when a is 16. I use conditional breakpoint in visual studio code like a == 16 but it's not work
debug not start at a is 16 but start at a is 20 .I set conditional breakpoint like this

```
breakpoint here >>>line 18   const gcd = (a, b) =>  b === 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
```

Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: since you only partially replied (and now even deleted your reply?), I repeat: _what if you put the body of the arrow function in its own line and put the breakpoint there?_

Comment: @starball   sorry

Comment: I'm trying to find a VS Code dup-target and failing. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35499140/11107541 (webstorm), https://stackoverflow.com/q/30664151/11107541 (chrome devtools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gcd function is one-line arrow function.

I think you did like below, right?

```
const gcd = (a, b) => {
  if(a===16) debugger;
  return b === 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
};
```

---

Note:

this gcd function is recursive function.

if you make breakpoint like this, it'll debug everytime first argument of gcd function is 16.

So, it'll works like bellows

For example,for [36, 20, 16].

```
  ==================
  gcd(36,20)
    gcd(20,16)
      gcd(16,4)   //debugger here because first argument is 16
        gcd(4,0)
          return 4
  result [4,16]  //36,20 => 4

  gcd(4,16)      //you maybe want debbugger here. 
    gcd(4, 4)
      gcd(4, 0)
       return 16
  result 16      //4,16 => 4

  answer:16
  ==================
```

To solve this problem, you have to debugger in reduce function like below.

```
nums.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur == 16) debugger;
  return gcd(acc, cur);
}, 0);
```

If you check your app enough, then change code style more cleanly like you did.

I hope my answer to help you.

Good luck.